# Como fazer soma com php ou SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Olá

Estou querendo somar o total de valores do resultado de uma query em PDO. Porém, ao executar o comando a seguinte mensagem aparece no console:

> Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_2.0/php/relatorioPorDiaTValorEntradas.php** on line **106**

A linha 106, informada na mensagem acima é:
$valorTotalEntradas = $valorTotalEntradas + $valor;

E o meu código todo é esse:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("con.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$id_empresa = $_GET['id_empresa'];
$data = $_GET['data'];

$tipo = "SAI";

$valorTotalEntradas=$pdo->prepare('SELECT valor FROM importa
                                                        WHERE data=:data
                                                        AND 
                                                      id_empresa=:id_empresa
                                                        AND tipo=:tipo');

$valorTotalEntradas->bindValue('id_empresa', $id_empresa);
$valorTotalEntradas->bindValue('data', $data);
$valorTotalEntradas->bindValue('tipo', $tipo);
$valorTotalEntradas->execute();

while ($linha=$valorTotalEntradas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $valor = $linha['valor'];
    $valorTotalEntradas = $valorTotalEntradas + $valor;

    $valorTotalEntradas = number_format($valorTotalEntradas,2,',','.');

    $return[] = array(
        'valorTotalEntradas' => $valorTotalEntradas
    );

}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

E se eu for fazer a soma, via SQL mesmo, como eu deveria pegar o resultado? Tenho que criar uma alias para o "SUM(valor)"?

Comment: Você está usando `$valorTotalEntradas` tanto para o pdo statement, quanto para a soma. Use outra variável para a soma.

Comment: Ou faça direto um `SELECT SUM(valor) FROM ...`.

Comment: Mas como recuperar o valor desse SELECT SUM(valor) FROM...?

Comment: @GustavoSevero faz `SELECT SUM(Valor) AS SomaValor FROM` e depois é só fazer `$valor = $linha['SomaValor']`